# Set a javascript variable in cake php and retrieve its value inside normal javascript

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-2.0

How does one set the javascript variable declared in cake php, for example

```
echo $this->Js->set('jsvalue','test');
```

I need to get the `jsvalue` value inside normal javascript

```
<script>
    // This will need to get value as 'test'
    console.info(jsvalue);
</script>
```

I am currently using [cakephp](http://cakephp.org/) (1.3). If this feature is not supported in version 1.3, please show me how it is implemented in version 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

It's set on `window.app` as an object to namespace it. Or, setting `$setVariable` on your JsHelper properties will change the namespace, to `window.<namespace>`.

So, it will be set like this:

`window.app = {"jsvalue" : "test"}`

Comment: So, how it can be taken in normal javascript as an variable. While I tried to take it as window.app.jsvalue gives an error  **window.app is undefined**.

Comment: I think it might be setting to something other than 'app', perhaps your app name? Try `window.<app_name>` instead.

Comment: My app folder name is 'app' itself. When i checked in firebug inside script cdata `window.app = {"jsvalue":"test"}`.but how it can retrevied...

Comment: It's just an object, so `window.app.jsvalue` = `'test'`.

Comment: While tried with above gives undefined error. `console.info(window.app.jsvalue)` gives error

Comment: View the source. How is it set? Are you setting text that might not be escaping properly (html, slashes, etc)?

Comment: I checked with above test code `echo $this->Js->set('jsvalue','test');` this is how I set in page.

Comment: I meant the html source where the js var is set. It should be in the HEAD tag in a script tag.

Answer (score 1):

If you have written javascript in the view part then directly you can use something like this.
I'm not getting what is `$this->Js->set('jsvalue','test');` instead of this if you use normal `$this->set('jsvalue','test');` and use it as below it should work.

```
<script>
    // This will need to get value as 'test'
    console.info(<?php echo $jsvalue; ?>);
</script>
```

Try this, this should do.

Comment: It should work, I think this is the only way to do it. Check the source code, check if the PHP value is actually set and check firebug for javascript errors.

Comment: @KevinVandenborne The firebug error is **syntax error** and cake error **Undefined variable: jsvalue**

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add $ symbol before jsvalue variable. I'm editing my answer.

You can try now, but make sure you've set that value from controller as other variable. Like this you can use any variable in the javascript.